# Oracle Object invalid PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Though this error is already discussed in stack overflow , am still stuck into the issue since am very new to PL/SQL procedures

when i execute the below procedure, am getting object invalid error:

```
enter code here
set serveroutput on         
create or replace procedure test_vinod_procs
is
test_id test_vino.emp_id%TYPE;
test_id test_vino.emp_name%TYPE;
BEGIN
SELECT emp_id,emp_name FROM test_vino INTO test_id, test_id ;
  dbms_output.put_line('ID=' || test_id || ', NAME=' || test_name);
END;
/
```

Kindly help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all, your variable names should be different - `test_id` has been used twice. Hope that's typo while posting this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax is:

```
Select ...
into ...
from ...
```

Also make sure you add a where clause because you can only select exactly 1 record when using a select ... into ... . When the query results in 0 records the code will raise an exception: NO_DATA_FOUND. When the query results in more than 1 record it will raise the exception: TOO_MANY_ROWS.

Comment: Hi,I did like SELECT emp_id,emp_name INTO test_id, test_name FROM test_vino where emp_id=1; Still same problem

Comment: thanks Rene. I got it. Just confused with my syntax a little bit.